# Add text according to chosen image Moodle

Tags: php, mysql, plugins, moodle, tcpdf

In my `Certificate` `plugin` in `Moodle`, I can choose from `4` `signatures`. The signature images are shown in the certificate and loaded trough CERT_IMAGE_SIGNATURE:

```
certificate_print_image($pdf, $certificate, CERT_IMAGE_SIGNATURE, $sigx, $sigy, '', '');
```

The file names are `jacob.png` `vanessa.png` `stan.png` `lilly.png.

How to add automatically `text` under the `image`? For example the `names` of the `person` from the signature `image`?

If I choose the file `jacob.png` from the dropdown list, It should load under the image also the names, here "Jacob Svenson".

Comment: your question is not bit clear. Try to clarify it and add more information.

Comment: I can get the file name from `$signaturename = $certificate->{'signature'.$sfx}` How to rename it, it comes out as `jacob.png`. Instead I need to show `Jacob Svenson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

in `/mod/certificate/type/xxx/certificate.php`

```
if (!empty($certificate->printsignature)) {
    certificate_print_image($pdf, $certificate, CERT_IMAGE_SIGNATURE, $sigx, $sigy, '', '');
    $signame = get_string($certificate->printsignature, 'certificate');
    certificate_print_text($pdf, $x, $y + 20, 'C', $fontserif, '', 20, $signame);
}
```

and in `/mod/certificate/lang/en/certificate.php` use the file name as the string id.

```
$string['jacob.png'] = 'Jacob Svenson';
```